# Issues with asynchronous behavior with NodeJS and Neo4j

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, asynchronous

I'm a self taught novice programmer working on a simple web application that uses Angular.js, Node.js, and the graph database neo4j. Right now I'm trying to get a a very basic query to execute and return data to the client. Upon execution I get an error which closes the server.

The following function is executed upon receiving a get request:

```
exports.test = function (req, res) {
var neo4j = require('neo4j');
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://localhost:7474');
var query = [
    'MATCH n',
    'RETURN n.name, n, labels(n)'
];
db.query(query, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {throw err};
    var data = results.map(function(result) {
            return result;
    });
    res.send(data)
}
)};
```

I get the following error in the console log: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

(I can provide the entire log if it would prove useful)

I would be extremely grateful for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is no issue. It's how Node.js works. Node.js is actually an asynchronous language, meaning that *it will execute the next statement WITHOUT waiting for the previous statement to be fully executed.* Currently, your code works on the assumption that the variable `data` will be defined before it is used with `res.send()`. However, this is NOT the case. What is actually happening is this:

1. Your code starts mapping the results from the query. The variable `data` is NOT yet defined.
2. You perform a method requiring `data`, which doesn't yet exist.
3. Your `data` variable is defined with the callback in your `results.map()`.

This is how the asynchronous behavior of NodeJS works. Basically, callbacks (functions within methods) execute LAST. Thus, you would want to put the `res.send()` statement in your callback, like so (note that defining the `data` variable is useless in the first place since it depends on a callback for its value):

```
results.map(function(result) {
    res.send(result);
});
```

It is a tough concept to wrap your head around...took me about a week. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @Bagavatu `map()` isn't really appropriate for this, you should use `forEach()` instead. And `res.send()` also isn't appropriate, because that will end the request once it's called (in this case, after the first result).

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the heads up. I simply used whatever functions were being used by the OP.

Comment: @Bagavatu there's nothing wrong with using `res.send()`, but you shouldn't use it in a loop :)

Comment: @robertklep haha yeah. I would personally stick all the results in an array and send the array at the last iteration.

Comment: That's completely non-sense! Array.prototype.map isn't asynchronous.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
robertkleps answer is the correct one.

Comment: Ah, but @joewhite86, map is asynchronously executed in Node.js. I ask that you please do your research and learn about the topic before downvoting answers.

Comment: @Bagavatu That's not true, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763613/is-node-js-array-map-asynchronous

Comment: @Bagavatu And further your answer would send an answer for each element in the array, so it's completely wrong, sorry.

Comment: In 2017, this is when you would use a Promise chain and/or async/await.

Resources to get you started: https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that you're passing an array as a query:

```
var query = [
    'MATCH n',
    'RETURN n.name, n, labels(n)'
];
db.query(query, function (err, results) { ... }
```

That should be a string, hence the `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

So you should either join the `query` array to make it a string, or don't use an array:

```
// solution 1
var query = [
    'MATCH n',
    'RETURN n.name, n, labels(n)'
].join(' ');

// solution 2
var query = 'MATCH n RETURN n.name, labels(n)';
```

Also, this code is a bit superfluous:

```
var data = results.map(function(result) {
  return result;
});
res.send(data);
```

Why not use this?

```
res.send(results);
```